# Error: list indices must be integers, not Cell

Tags: python, google-api, google-sheets

I want to write data to google sheets using python. Right now I've made the following to achieve this:

```
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

sh = gc.open('test')

worksheet = sh.worksheet('Sheet1')

cell_list = []
cell_data = []

for e in range(len(scholar_key)):
   cell_list.append('B' + str(e))

for d in scholar_key:
   cell_data.append(d['titel'])

cell_range = worksheet.range(cell_list[1]+ ":" +cell_list[-1])

for i in cell_range:
  i.value = cell_data[i]

worksheet.update_cells(cell_range)
```

But I keep getting the following error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Cell` on line 28 (which is the line where i.value = cell_data[i] is stated). What am I doing wrong? And another question is how to increment the counter, because now the index starts at 0 and counts to 19. However, I want the counter to start from 1 and count to 20 (for the columns, so that I only have values in my data_list array ranging from B1 to B20).

Comment: Please post the full `traceback`, it helps massively for debugging.

Comment: line 28? what line is it exactly at the given code?!

Comment: Please also try to make your code usable (e.g. include `import gspread`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this loop, `i` will be instances of `Cell` not numeric indices

```
for i in cell_range:
  i.value = cell_data[i]
```

You can instead use something like this

```
for index, cell in enumerate(cell_range):
  cell.value = cell_data[index]
```

Comment: You are a hero man, this worked! Tnx for your clear explanation

Comment: The enumerate function also provides a nice solution for the counter problem! Tnx again: 

for index, e in enumerate(scholar_key, start=1):
 cell_list.append('B' + str(index))